# What is considered the best most recent, up to date English translation of Newton’s Principia?

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history

my name is Sam. Welcome to my question.

I want to find the most best English translation of Newton’s principia, PDF is ok but I would prefer an actual book I can buy. Footnotes would be acceptable too, and it’s extremely important that all Newton’s Euclidean constructions are included in detail.

Thank you, my good friends

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica#English_translations_2

Comment: Thanks, though all of those are internet based and I’ve used a couple, I’m hoping to find a published book I can buy in paperback or some such

Comment: In other words, something available from somewhere like amazon, though when I search for newton I’m just overwhelmed

Comment: You can take a PDF to a print shop and have them make a paperback for you. I have no idea what a reasonable price is, though.

Comment: Thanks, though If anyone else knows a worthy paperback to by I’d appreciate it

Comment: Probably the [1999 edition of the translation by I. Bernard Cohen and Anne Whitman](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0520290879). But see also the references given in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy's entry for [Newton’s *Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/newton-principia/).